# Package imports

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have one `package` called `model` and two files which both are using the model package (user.go, task.go).

My question: In both files I am importing the `appengine` and `appengine\datasotre` libs, do I need to do so?, or there is a better way of doing this?

user.go

```
package model

import "appengine"
import "appengine/datastore"


type User struct {
  name
}
func (u *User) Save(c appengine.Context) (*User, error){
}
```

task.go

```
package model
import "appengine"
import "appengine/datastore"

type Task struct {
  name
}

func (u *Task) Save(c appengine.Context) (*Task, error){
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Imports work per file, not per package.

I recommend [installing `goimports`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports) to handle imports for you.